# Password with special characters in connectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to connect to my Dynamics CRM 365 on premise instance from an ASP NET application. My problem is that the account for connection has a password like: T,jL4O&vc%t;30

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRM365" connectionString="AuthType=AD;Url=http://crm.xxx.com/CRM365; Domain=test; Username=test; Password=T,jL4O&vc%t;30" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have the following error: vc is not defined

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What error you got so far?

Comment: You'll need to escape it or quote it, but it depends on which provider you're using. How you get there depends on whether you're reading it from a configuration file or building it in code. Please [edit] your question to provide details.

Comment: Either way, I suggest you use a connection string builder (`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` for SQL Server, for example) and see how it constructs the connection string based on the password you assign to it. That should give you an idea.

Comment: @madreflection i have edit my question. I'm reading it from a connectionstring

Comment: Which *provider* are you using? Is it the *CData* provider for Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In this example I see two things:

1. A `&` in xml should be escaped with `&amp;` (Good explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953))
2. A `;` in a connection string, you should wrap the password in single quotes

So this should work for you:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRM365" connectionString="AuthType=AD;Url=http://crm.xxx.com/CRM365; Domain=test; Username=test; Password='T,jL4O&amp;vc%t;30'" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Edit (just tried it for myself):
Additionally, another variant is to use escaped double quotes:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRM365" connectionString="AuthType=AD;Url=http://crm.xxx.com/CRM365; Domain=test; Username=test; Password=&quot;T,jL4O&amp;vc%t;30&quot;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Summary:
Use either `password='T,jL4O&amp;vc%t;30';` or `password=&quot;T,jL4O&amp;vc%t;30&quot;;`

Comment: To escape a `'` in a parameter value that is enclosed in `'`, just double it like `''`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can set random password for connection string. Please remove ';' from password if ';' occurs then connectionstring will interpret as password completed

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CRM365" connectionString="AuthType=AD;Url=http://crm.xxx.com/CRM365; Domain=test; Username=test; Password=T,jL4O&vc%t30" />
```